# Saving a file is canceled if Form1 is focused

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave...  
MsgBox "Why"
```

If Form1 is focused - the MsgBox doesn't appear. Saving procedure is canceled.
Plese don't tell me that the end user must click outside the form to save the file.
Form1 is not modal.

Comment: how do you initiate saving procedure?

Comment: tested with clean workbook, new form, `thisworkbook.save` button on form and your given code -> worked.

Comment: @Jook, please place a textbox on a form, place the cursor inside it, or just click on form header. Then press Ctrl+S, and see if the MsgBox appears or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please place a textbox on a form, place the cursor inside it, or just
>   click on form header. Then press Ctrl+S, and see if the MsgBox appears
>   or not. – Alegro 49 mins ago

In such a case simply paste this code in your userform. This code is slightly modified from my other [answer](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?554724-RESOLVED-Capture-Tab-Press-Textbox).

**CODE (Tried And Tested)**:

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState _
Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

Private Myarray(255) As Byte

Dim Cntrl_Key As Boolean, Sletter_Key As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 17 Then Cntrl_Key = True
    If KeyCode = 83 Then Sletter_Key = True
    Call ShowKey
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshKeyState(RefreshState As Boolean)
   If RefreshState Then
      Call GetKeyboardState(Myarray(0))
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowKey()
    '~~> Check for Ctrl + S
    If Cntrl_Key = True And Sletter_Key = True Then
        '~~> Save Workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Cntrl_Key = False
        Sletter_Key = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**:

[image]

**NOTE**: This is not a foolproof method as a user may press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then types something else and then presses the "S" key then the code will still fire. We can include a small check to see if the next key pressed after <kbd>CTRL</kbd> was pressed is <kbd>S</kbd> or not. If not then set it to false again... For example

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState _
Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

Private Myarray(255) As Byte

Dim Cntrl_Key As Boolean, Vletter_Key As Boolean
Dim OtherLetter As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 17 Then Cntrl_Key = True
    If KeyCode = 83 Then Vletter_Key = True
    If KeyCode <> 83 And KeyCode <> 17 Then
        OtherLetter = True
    End If
    Call ShowKey
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshKeyState(RefreshState As Boolean)
   If RefreshState Then
      Call GetKeyboardState(Myarray(0))
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowKey()
    '~~> Check for Ctrl + S
    If Cntrl_Key = True And OtherLetter = True Then
        Cntrl_Key = False
    ElseIf Cntrl_Key = True And Vletter_Key = True Then
        '~~> Save Workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Cntrl_Key = False
        Vletter_Key = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth, Thank You for your solution and effort. I'm really surprised that I must write all this code for such a minor thing, like - Ctrl S. Is there any reasonable explanation why Microsoft prefer not to save a file if a form is focused ?

Comment: When you press Ctrl + S, the instruction is sent to the active window. Now it depends on the active window on how to interpret the instruction. When the form or a textbox is active then Ctrl + S doesn't mean anything to it so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but, Ctrl+S should be Ctrl+S regardless where is my cursor. Tommorow morning, I will maybe discover, that I must write an additional code if my mouse is in the left, and not in the right hand.

Comment: That is because from day 1 you have been told that the shortcut key globally accepted for saving is Ctrl+S. But The userform or the active textbox unfortunately doesn't know that :)